# SOAP Response to Tree etc

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, soap, response

I have a Question About Soap Responses and how to handle them.
I get a xmlstring from my Response, but have to convert it into this Class to Output into
a specific Window with a view of a tree.

```
public ExampleTree() { }

    public ExampleTree(string nodeContent, List<ExampleTree> subColl)
    {
        DisplayContent = displayContent;
        SubCollection = subCollection;
    }

    public string DisplayContent { get; set; }
    public List<ExampleTree> SubCollection { get; set; }
```

Does anyone knows which way is the smartest? The hard Thing is that it has to be
generic so I can not use Service References. I just found hardcoded usage, but what
about this case(with subcollections etc.)?

Comment: you can use LINQ to XML API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netcore-3.1 and build the expected object from it.

Comment: It is hard to give answer without seeing xml.  The Service Reference uses Xml Serialization which means the c# classes have to match the xml structure.

Comment: the Problem is that I don't have a specific Soap Response, it can be everytime different, so i can't say take this element and use that, because it depends on which XML I am parsing.

Comment: Do you have WSDL or ASMX?